# Diffence between /etc/locale.conf and /etc/default/locale

Tags: locale, kde-neon

I'm running KDE neon 5.20 and found two files `/etc/locale.conf` and `/etc/default/locale` with similar content. What's the difference between these two files and which one should I edit to change the system locale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some experiments, I've determined that KDE neon respects the locale settings in `/etc/default/locale`, but ignores the locale settings in `/etc/locale.conf`. I still don't understand why Ubuntu uses a different location for the locale file, but I came to the conclusion that on Ubuntu based distributions it's necessary to use `/etc/default/locale` to set the locale. Also, I just replaced `/etc/default/locale` with a symlink to the `/etc/locale.conf`, and everything works fine, but now I have only one file with the locale settings.

Answer (score 3):

Many application softwares need the LANG environment variable to work. So most distros have a startup script to set LANG after login.

So where does the startup script read the LANG config from? It's different among distros, e.g.

- Debian default console login startup script reads `/etc/default/locale`
- Slackware default console login startup script [dot-sources](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#dot) `/etc/profile.d/lang.sh`
- KDE Plasma reads `~/.config/plasma-localerc`
- Some other distros read `/etc/locale.conf`

Systemd doesn't know what distro it is installed on. So when you're gonna modify the config with localectl, localectl detects whether `/etc/locale.conf` exists. If it exists, then localectl modifies it, or  it modifies `/etc/default/locale` as a fallback.

As far as Ubuntu(Non-GUI) is concerned, in case `/etc/locale.conf` exists, you will find that no matter how you run localectl, the LANG variable is retained after reboot. That's because Ubuntu uses `/etc/default/locale`, and localectl modified a file which will never be read by Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Different distributions or versions of Linux employ one or the other. As a case in point, the documentation for Debian 10 refers mainly to `/etc/default/locale` (e.g. `man update-locale`). Its systemd-related parts refer also to `/etc/locale.conf` (e.g. `man locale.conf`).

A brief test shows that `localectl` (also part of Debian 10's systemd) reports the contents of `/etc/default/locale` as system locale, unless `/etc/locale.conf` exists as well: in this case it apparently takes precedence.

I am using `/etc/default/locale` exclusively (again, on a current version of Debian). My rational is as follows: this one can be appropriate for Debian, either one is appropriate for system, so in sum it's a clear choice.

Comment: I still don't understand why there are two files. If I set `LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8` in **/etc/default/locale** and `LC_TIME=en_GB.UTF-8` in **/etc/locale.conf**, what will the LC_TIME be as a result (I don't have Ubuntu installed at the moment to check this)?

Comment: @popov895 Well I guess there are two different lineages. An older one that employs `/etc/locale.conf` and a newer one that employs `/etc/default/locale`.